# TypeScript | Socket.IO : How to refer to the client object

Tags: javascript, socket.io, typescript, ecmascript-6, phaser-framework

I'm testing things with TypeScript,socket.io and the game engine Phaser and working on Visual Studio

Here is a sample of my socket.io events handling class

```
class RemoteEventHandlers{
    ...
    constructor(socket,players){
        this.socket = socket;
        this.players = players;
    }
    ...
    onSocketConnection(client): void{
        client.on('disconnect', this.onClientDisconnect.bind(this));
        client.on('new player', this.onNewPlayer.bind(this));
        client.on('move player', this.onMovePlayer.bind(this));
    }
    onClientDisconnect(): void{
        let disconnectedPlayer = this.searchPlayerById(this.id);
        if (!disconnectedPlayer)
        {
            console.log("not found ", this.id);
            return;
        }
        this.players.splice(this.players.indexOf(disconnectedPlayer), 1);
        this.broadcast.emit('remove player', { id: this.id });
    }
    ...
}
```

I need to access `this.id` and `this.broadcast` of the current scope and at the same time I need to access `this.players` and the method `this.searchPlayerByid()` of the class (that's why I used `.bind(this)`)

I'd really appreciate if someone could give me some hints.

**Update**

This code is working:

```
onSocketConnection(client): void{
    this.client = client;
    client.on('disconnect', () => {this.client = client; this.onClientDisconnect();});
    client.on('new player', data => { this.client = client; this.onNewPlayer(data);});
    client.on('move player', data => { this.client = client; this.onMovePlayer(data);});
}
```

And I can access the socket id by using `this.client.id` in my callback functions

Answer (score 0):

You need access to both the `context` this sent down from the caller and the class scope `this`. The only place where *both* exist *is at the point of function registration*. So instead of :

```
client.on('disconnect', this.onClientDisconnect.bind(this));
```

Do:

```
let self = this;
client.on('disconnect', function(){self.onClientDisconnect(this.id,this.broadcast));
```

## More

See the tip about arrow functions with libraries that use `this` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured out what was wrong in my code, i just replaced `client.on('new player', this.onNewPlayer.bind(this));` by `client.on('new player', data => { this.client = client; this.onNewPlayer(data)});` and that works

Comment: Also if I do `let self = this;
client.on('disconnect', function(){self.onClientDisconnect(this.id,this.broadcast));
` Visual Studio throw me the error `The property 'id' does not exist on type 'RemoteEventHandlers'`